# Program to block an IP temporarily with iptables

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

Is there a program on Debian to block an IP address **temporarily** just by launching a command (specifying the IP and the duration)?

With iptables/ip6tables alone I can create a rule, but I would then have to delete manually. I also use fail2ban, but I don't think I can block an arbitrary IP address that did not satisfy any of the fail2ban rules.

Comment: For example create the rule and schedule with `at` the rule deletion command, something like `echo "iptables -d rest_of_rule" | at now+30m`

Comment: @Dan This sound like a good solution. Actually, if you write an answer in the form of a little bash script that can take the IP and the duration as input parameters, I would accept it!

Answer (score 8):

You need to create an ipset so iptables can match against it.
Note **timeout 0** means the default is never expire.

```
ipset create temp_hosts hash:ip timeout 0
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set -j DROP  --match-set temp_hosts src
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m set -j DROP  --match-set temp_hosts src
```

Now that our set is created we can start adding ip addresses (timeout unit: seconds).

```
ipset add temp_hosts 1.1.1.2 timeout 400
```

Note should you need these to survive a reboot you need to save and load the rules.

```
ipset save -f /path/ipset.save
ipset restore -f /path/ipset.save
```

These can be automated with cron or systemd.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. One can indeed create an ipset systemd init file as documented [here](https://linux-audit.com/blocking-ip-addresses-in-linux-with-iptables/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this script, inspired by Dan's comment:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -I INPUT -s $1 -j DROP
at ${2:-now+1hour} <<<"iptables -D INPUT -s $1 -j DROP"
```

Save it as `/usr/local/sbin/blockip` and run `blockip 1.2.3.4` or `blockip 1.2.3.4 now+2hours`. By default the IP is blocked for 1 hour.

You can replace DROP with REJECT if you prefer REJECT semantics.

Comment: If you intend on a long lists of rejects, having a lot of rules will slow iptables down a lot.  **ipset** has you covered all options together.  You could end up with hundreds of cron jobs which is also less than ideal.